# converting a 10-30 receptacle to a 6-50

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, receptacle

I have a 10-30 receptacle in my garage that has never been used. It is attached to a safety switch.  I have added a picture to show what is there. Wiring into the box looks to be individual wires run through a conduit to my panel.

My questions are as follows:

1. The wires look to be hot, hot, and ground coming into the safety switch, which I know shouldn't be the case, but looks that way.  From there they run to the 10-30r receptacle.  If those are truly two hot wires, can i just replace the receptacle with a 6-50r?
2. If I want to upgrade from 30A to a 50A receptacle, is it as easy as replacing the breaker in the panel from a 30A to a 50A?  I noticed the wire is #8 and rated to 55A.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Changing to 6-30 or 6-50 will require changing of the grey wire to green or bare, maybe not needed if the conduit is metal.  Check the panel also, if a sub panel, the green should be on the ground bus, but by using green on a 10-30r, checking is required.

Comment: Why do you think two hots and a ground is wrong? That's 100% correct for a 240v circuit. I was gonna ask why the ground is wired with blue, but I guess it could be grey. Either way, it's the wrong color. Good news is that you've got conduit, so it's easy to replace with green, or, just pull it as the EMT should be suitable as the ground.

Comment: I'm looking to add an EV charger by using the existing wiring. I haven't looked in the panel yet to verify the green actually goes to the ground bus.  My next move is to verify all that at the panel.  I just wanted to get some info as I move along. The conduit is metal, fyi.

Comment: I only meant it was wrong as in that isnt how these old receptacles were meant to be wired...at least from what I've read.

Comment: @FreeMan  OP has/had a 10-30 there.  Somebody goofed up on the wire colours.  For a 6-30 it would be okay on top, bad on bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### TL;DR Don't Install ANY Receptacle, Hardwire the EVSE

> *I'm looking to add an EV charger by using the existing wiring.*

Any good quality EV charger designed for permanent installation can be **hardwired**. That is what you want to do here. So the question shouldn't be "how do I convert to a 6-50" it should be "how do I use this to hardwire an EV charger (EVSE)".

There are some definite advantages, including *not* needing the required in most areas (others coming soon) GFCI breaker. Install NACS - anything you get now will either use NACS directly (Tesla) or have an adapter (Ford, GM, Stellantis, etc.).

The good news is you are in conduit, so anything wrong can be replaced, if needed.

If you actually need 50A of charging (40A actual, 50A due to continuous derate) then you need 8 AWG wires. If you can make do with 30A (24A actual), which most people can just fine unless they drive a **lot** or have multiple EVs, then 10 AWG is big enough.

You need:

- 2 hot wires (black, red, blue, yellow, etc. - can be 2 of the same color or different colors) wires from panel to this box.
- 2 hot wires (black, red, blue, yellow, etc. - can be 2 of the same color or different colors) wires from this box to your EVSE.
- If you don't have a continuous metal ground via conduit (certain types of conduit) then you need a green or bare wire for ground.

Wire size *minimum* based on circuit size. Circuit size is determined by the breaker and you can configure your EVSE for anything up to that size.

You obviously don't need neutral. If any wires are the wrong color(s), you can use the old wire to pull through a new wire of the correct color.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the wiring I see, the use of a NEMA 10-30 circuit was improper, and should be immediately corrected to a NEMA 6-30.  The 10-30 socket does not have ground and was outlawed in 1965. It continues to be sold only for exact in-place replacement of broken sockets on dryers, which alone were allowed to use that socket until 1996.

> I noticed the wire is #8 and rated to 55A.

Be careful with "wishful thinking" - we see a lot of that from novice EVers doing their first high power circuit. An EV is the most extreme load a house will ever carry, and any flaw in the work WILL be found and made crispy.

#8 wire is actually 40A for type NM, UF and TW.... and 50A for other types. There is no way to use the 55A rating.

The Fastest Charge Possible (tm) is a hollow pursuit anyway.  A 50 amp circuit is ***gross*** overkill for home charging.  [See Technology Connections' excellent video on the basics of home charging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w), and 32:55 gets right down to brass tacks on *necessary* circuit sizing.  Almost everyone can make it with a 20A circuit (16A actual charge) - and a 30A circuit (24A actual) is "plennnnty".

8 AWG wire is good for 40A in NM, UF or TW types, and 50A otherwise.  This can support a 32A or 40A EV station, respectively; however, EV charging is such a brutal load that running these wires at thermal limits for hours is risky.  I'm also not so confident ALL the wire in the circuit is #8; some seems like #10 to my eyes and that would be reasonable for a 30A circuit.

Of course the cheapest ["travel unit style"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_naDg-guomA&t=676s) EVSEs (['chargers'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMxB7zA-e4Y)) only support one level 2 speed, but that can be solved several ways.

- A "wall unit" can be used, and preferably, hardwired.  Hard-wiring the unit avoids the need for a GFCI breaker, since an EVSE is itself a GFCI. (and putting a GFCI on a GFCI is kinda dumb).
- Some travel units come with [a variety of plug adapters](https://shop.tesla.com/product/gen-2-nema-adapters). The adapter [has a microchip inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlUAz.png) that tells the EVSE the correct amps for the plug.  (so you can't homebrew an adapter unless the EV's socket <= the house socket).
- Travel units can be purchased for a variety of socket sizes, e.g. [this Dewalt 16A unit](https://www.dewalt.com/product/dxpaev016/dewalt-portable-electric-vehicle-ev-120-240v-level-2-charger-16-amps-csa-certified-indooroutdoor-nema-6-20-5-15-adapter-included-25-ft-cable) with a NEMA 6-20 socket.